# How can I optionally mock geocoder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, cucumber

I'd like to be able to mock the results of the [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) gem in some of my tests.

I use RSpec and Cucumber. In cucumber I'd like to default to mocking the Geocoder results, but be able to turn it back on again by adding a tag. That would be perfect! Something similar for RSpec would be good too. It would speed up my tests enormously.

I know there are some gems out there for doing similar things, e.g. [sunspot_test](https://github.com/collectiveidea/sunspot_test) for [sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot). Is there anything similar for geocoder?

Comment: im using `vcr` gem for remote serices, check it out! It can be very useful in you situation. https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr

Comment: Mikhail - Would you like add this as an answer and I'll mark it correct? The other answer may be more correct, but using VCR worked and was pretty easy to set up. Cheers, Graeme

Comment: Sure, why not, im glad that can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im using `vcr` gem for remote services, check it out! It can be very useful in your situation. [github.com/myronmarston/vcr](http://github.com/myronmarston/vcr)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/) to stub and mock calls. If you do something like (and I'm just making this up because I don't know the GeoCoder syntax):

```
GeoCoder.get_data(x, y)
```

And that's something you want to stub out and force to return something else, mocha allows you to do:

```
GeoCoder.stubs(:get_data).with(x, y).returns(my_own_variable)
```

And that will make any call to GeoCode.get_data, when passed in x and y, to return your custom variable. However, this stub will last for all subsequent calls during your test, so you can unstub it by calling:

```
GeoCoder.unstub(:get_data)
```

And that completely restores that method to normal.

In terms of Rspec, in a teardown block you can unstub. In terms of Cucumber, you can add a tag like @stubs_geocoder before scenarios, and within `features/support/env.rb` you can add this:

```
Before('@stubs_geocoder') do
    # add your stub calls
end

After('@stubs_geocoder') do
    # unstub
end
```